# REST Api with Multithreading for handling Files in Spring Boot

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpool

Is their any way so that i can make use of Multithreading concept to call the execution in parallel and make execution faster for created `@RestController` which will accepts a `String` and `List<MultipartFile>` as request parameters, and the code is working fine.Problem here is if i'm parsing one file after other via a for loop. Time taken for execution is more.

> Below is Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/csvUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<String> csvUpload(@RequestParam String parentPkId, @RequestParam List<MultipartFile> file)
            throws IOException {
        log.info("Entered method csvUpload() of DaoController.class");
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        String temp = parentPkId.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]", "");
        for (MultipartFile f : file) {
            String resp = uploadService.csvUpload(temp, f);
            response.add(resp);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

from controller, i'm calling `uploadService.csvUpload()` method where i'm parsing the files one after the other as i'm using For loop.

**Below is my UploadService Class**

```
public String csvUpload(String parentPkId, MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            int header = 0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // TO SKIP HEADER
                if(header == 0) {
                    header++;  
                    continue;
                }
                header++;
                //Use Comma As Separator
                String[] csvDataSet = line.split(",");
                //Saving it to DB

        }catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Successfully Uploaded "+ file.getOriginalFilename();
    }
```

> How to make this Controller as a Multithreaded so that processing is parallel and fast. I'm new to Multithreading and I tried by making use of `Callable` interface but the `Call()` method will not take parameters.

any leads and suggestion are welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure but may  @Async annotation solve your problems

Comment: @SHAHAKASH any code bit would help me, if you can provide

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-creating-asynchronous-methods-using-as

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to create a Class which will implement callable as below and store futures in a list and finally process the futures as below

```
public class ProcessMutlipartFile implements Callable<String>
{
   private Mutlipartfile file; 
   private String temp;
   private UploadService uploadService;
   public ProcessMutlipartFile(Mutlipartfile file,String temp, UploadService uploadService )
   {
       this.file=file;
       this.temp=temp,
       this.uploadService=uploadService;
   }

   public String call() throws Exception 
   {

    return   uploadService.csvUpload(temp, file);
    }

 }
```

in your controller create a list of future object

```
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)
List< Future<String> > futureList = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
     .
     .
     .
         for (MultipartFile f : file) {
                    futureList.add(executor.submit(new ProcessMutlipartFile(file ,temp,uploadService));
                }
```

finally in your controller

```
 for (Future f :futureList)
 {
  response.add(f.get());
  }

//shuttingdown the Executor
executor.shutdown();
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

You can execute the uploading code using [parallel stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html)

```
    List<String> response = file.parallelStream().map(f -> uploadService.csvUpload(temp, f))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> You can execute streams in serial or in parallel. When a stream executes in parallel, the Java runtime partitions the stream into multiple substreams. Aggregate operations iterate over and process these substreams in parallel and then combine the results.