# Calling REST APIs in Spring and multithreading

Tags: spring, multithreading, rest

My Spring app will call couple of external APIs with each get request.
I understand that Spring can handle a large number of calls at a time.

But here I read about multithreading

[REST Api with Multithreading for handling Files in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54899271/rest-api-with-multithreading-for-handling-files-in-spring-boot)

So I was wondering:

1. Does Spring implement multi-threading out of the box?
2. Would using async http calls to the external APIs increase the performance, load tolerance of my App/RESTAPI?

Comment: 1. In this case no, since you most like will generate a set of request for a loop. 2. It certainly will increase the performance of your app. I don't know what you mean by load tolerance.

Comment: For No. 1. Just make sure I understood correctly: Spring does not implement multithreading/concurrency? I don't get how does a Spring REST API handle multiple concurrent API requests from multiple users?       for 2. I meant in situations of high load as in many concurrent requests to my API, currently I use OKHttp synchronously to make requests an external API (whenever my own Spring app receives a request).

Comment: You want to dozens of requests, lets say, from a bean. This is not the same as handling incoming requests. Yes, Spring implements parallelism, but that does not mean that everything you do will be done in parallel.

Comment: Ok got it. So for requests made to my API; is there a limit/number that will then requires me to add more threads/ more parallelism?   And if each of the incoming calls will in turn generate an http request is there I specific point/ amount of traffic that will dictate that I make the http requests that I make in async fashion rather than sync??

Comment: Well certainly can be some limits on how many requests can be made in parallel, but OkHttp should take care of this. Also, there is no point in sending the requests sequentially, since the requests can consume a lot of time to complete (in general we are talking about milliseconds here) and also OkHttp has a great support for async.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and explanation, if you want you can add an answer and I will accept it.